# PowerShell - Reduces the size of images

Tags: powershell

I try to make a script that reduces the size of images in a folder. But I have always a error message. 
I must reduce the size in the same folder and subfolders

Can you help to build my script please?

Thank you in advance.

Here is the script :

```
$source = "U:\TEST\Compression\images"
$exclude_list = "(Imprimerie|Photos)"

$source_listephotos = Get-ChildItem $source -Recurse | where {$_.FullName -notmatch $exclude_list}

foreach ( $source_photos in $source_listephotos ) {

$source_photos

Resize-Image -InputFile $source_photos.FullName -Scale 30 -OutputFile (Join-Path $source $source_photos.Name) -Verbose

}
```

And here the error message :

```
    Exception calling "Save" with "1" argument(s): "A generic error occurred in GDI+."
At C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\Modules\Resize-Image\Resize-Image.psm1:70 char:9
+         $img2.Save($OutputFile);
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExternalException
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using (I assume) the [Resize-Image](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Resize-Image-A-PowerShell-3d26ef68) module.

The reported problem is that the path's file format is not supported.

Without further data, I assume that you're passing a full object to the OutputFile. To fix this, try specifying the Name property.

```
$source = "U:\TEST\Compression\images"
$destination = "U:\TEST\Compression\image_resizer"
$exclude_list = @("*Imprimerie","*Photos*")

$source_listephotos = Get-ChildItem $source -Exclude $exclude_list -Recurse

foreach ( $source_photos in $source_listephotos ) {
    Resize-Image -InputFile $source_photos.FullName -Scale 30 -OutputFile (Join-Path $destination $source_photos.Name) -Verbose
}
```

As mentioned by the other answer, the InputFile should also be changed.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
Can I reduce the size for a image .png ? The modification of the script modify image extension.

Comment: I'm sorry, It's me, I have made a mistake in $source.

Comment: I have an other problem. I must exclude some folders with photos but the parameter -exclude does not work. How I can do ?

Comment: @pcarrey : Running `get-help get-childitem -Parameter exclude` shows that it accepts `a path element or pattern, such as "*.txt"`. Depending on what you have in the exclude_list, this might be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use $source_photos.fullname i.e.

```
... Resize-Image -InputFile $($source_photos.fullname) -Scale ....
```